# Permutations Integers 1 to 9 all even numbers stay in their natural positions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I have these questions regarding Inclusion-Exclusion Principle two of them have been bothering me. The questions goes:

How many ways can we write the numbers 1 to 9 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] if:

1. All even numbers stay in their natural positions
2. No even numbers stay in their natural positions
3. All odd numbers stay in their natural positions
4. No odd numbers stay in their natural positions

I solved no. 2 and 4 using the principle of inclusion-exclusion but haven't been able to solve 1 and 4. Should the answers of 2 and 4 be of help?

Comment: I am understanding correct? The sequence is:

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

and you want the number of permutations (even stay in same position) such that for example:

3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

Is such an permutation?

Comment: There are nine numbers. The even numbers are fixed which leaves 5 free spots. So the number of ways is $5!$.

Comment: @thinkingeye Yes exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To 1**:

You have five places where you can put the five odd numbers (1, 3, 5, 7 and 9):

_ 2 _ 4 _ 6 _ 8 _

So you don't need to bother about the even numbers. The number of different permutations will be: 5! = 120

**To 3**:

You have four places where you can put the four even numbers (2, 4, 6 and 8):

1 _ 3 _ 5 _ 7 _ 9

So you don't need to bother about the odd numbers. The number of different permutations will be: 4! = 24